# Req.Body is returning "undefined" values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have added `body-parser` to my application `app.js` file. I have a `routes` folder and a `controllers` folder which handles my request.

Initially, I did not have `body-parser` added to my application. When I added `body-parser` and console logged `req.body` I got an empty object. When I console logged `req.body.email`, `req.body.password`, and `req.body.displayName` values from `postman` were read as undefined.

app.js

```
let createError = require('http-errors');
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let assert = require('assert');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

let usersRouter = require('./routes/user');

let app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/user', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

// MongoDB Connection
const db = {};
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECT_URL, (err, client) => {
  // Connection works dont worry about it
});

module.exports = app;
```

routes/user.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const user = require('../controllers/user');

router.post('/', user.createUser);
router.delete('/:id', user.deleteUser);
router.get('/:id', user.loginUser);

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/user.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const Joi = require('joi');
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

exports.createUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Request body: ', req.body);
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const displayName = req.body.displayName;

    console.log('Email: ', email);
    console.log('Password: ', password);
    console.log('Display name: ', displayName);
};
```

Comment: Try chaning app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); to true.

Comment: And remove these : 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Comment: This may happen, if you request this route without `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`, maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you are adding content-type header in postman `content-type :   application/json` also in body tab select raw and beside raw select json from drop-down list.
Check this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDhcl.png

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to send form-data with Postman which sends a multipar body, body parser cannot handle multipart bodies. For handling multipart bodies you have to use a different module, I normally use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

With multer installed you just have to include it and it as middleware (under you body-parser for instance) using none() since in this case you want to handle text-only multipart body (More information about this in [multer docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

```
let multer = require('multer');
app.use(multer().none());
```

Besides that I wanted to mention you are including two body parsers in your code, the express body parser

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

and an external body-parser

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Pick one, you don't need both, the best option for me would be to keep the one that comes with express, this way you don't have to install any more external packages.